# How to do "Navigation Property binding of aggregations" in xml

Tags: xml, data-binding, fragment, sapui5

I'm developing a UI5 application.

I have the following odata entity:

```
<EntityType Name="order">
    <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="id"/>
    </Key>
    <Property Name="id" Nullable="false" Type="Edm.Guid"/>
    <Property Name="creatorId" Type="Edm.Guid"/>
    <NavigationProperty FromRole="To_Order" Name="Creator" Relationship="bwm.UserOrder" ToRole="From_User"/>
</EntityType>
<EntityType Name="User">
    <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="id"/>
    </Key>
    <Property Name="id" Nullable="false" Type="Edm.Guid"/>
    <Property Name="name" Type="Edm.String"/>
    <Property Name="phone" Type="Edm.String"/>
    <Property Name="avatar" Type="Edm.String"/>
    <NavigationProperty FromRole="From_User" Name="OrderSet" Relationship="bwm.UserOrder" ToRole="To_Order"/>
</EntityType>
```

I've simplified the entity model. Basically there's the `Order` and `User` entity, on `Order` entity, there's a **navigation property** `Creator` which reference to `User` entity.

I want to define a fragment which displays user information, I want to bind the UI elements relatively to a user :

```
<HBox  xmlns="sap.m">
    <items>
        <Image src="{avatar}"/>
        <VBox>
            <items>
                <Label text="{name}"/>
                <Label text="{phone}"/>
            </items>
        </VBox>
    </items>
</HBox>
```

Now I have the page which is displaying a list of Orders, but I **don't know how to element binding the fragment to the `Creator` navigation property**:

```
<GrowingList threshold="10"
            items="{
                path: '/OrderSet'
            }">
    <items>
        <CustomListItem >
            <content>
                <core:Fragment fragmentName="xxx.fragment.User" type="XML"/>
            </content>
        </CustomListItem >
    </items>
</GrowingList>
```

How can I set the binding path of the fragment to the navigation property `Creator`?

=============================================================
**PS**: I googled around and find some solution, these solution is not what I want, because it bound the fragment's data binding tightly to the data model, how the solution works:

first, when binding items path, expand the `Creator` navigation property:

```
<GrowingList threshold="10"
            items="{
                path: '/OrderSet',
                paramters: {expand: 'Creator'}
            }">
    <items>
        <CustomListItem >
            <content>
                <core:Fragment fragmentName="xxx.fragment.User" type="XML"/>
            </content>
        </CustomListItem >
    </items>
</GrowingList>
```

second, change the data binding of the fragment to `Creator/xxx`:

```
 <HBox  xmlns="sap.m">
    <items>
        <Image src="{Creator/avatar}"/>
        <VBox>
            <items>
                <Label text="{Creator/name}"/>
                <Label text="{Creator/phone}"/>
            </items>
        </VBox>
    </items>
</HBox>
```

This makes the fragment useless, if I want to use it in a page displaying a user list because in `UserSet`, a `User` doesn't have a property `Creator/name`. What I want is the fragment to be general, it can be used anywhere as long as the root binding path is a user entity instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

A cleaner way to implement this is to use [new XML Templating syntax](https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/docs/guide/5ee619fc1370463ea674ee04b65ed83b.html) that will be introduced in `1.30.x`. See the `<template:with>` tags used below.

```xml
<mvc:View
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:form="sap.ui.layout.form"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:template="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.template/1">

  <!-- "meta" model's binding context MUST point to an entity type -->
  <template:with path="meta>com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1.Badge" var="badge">
      <form:SimpleForm>
        <form:title>
            <core:Title text="{path: 'badge>HeadLine', formatter: 'sap.ui.model.odata.AnnotationHelper.format'}"/>
        </form:title>

        <Label text="{path: 'badge>Title/Label', formatter: 'sap.ui.model.odata.AnnotationHelper.format'}"/>
        <Text text="{path: 'badge>Title/Value', formatter: 'sap.ui.model.odata.AnnotationHelper.format'}"/>

        <Label text="{path: 'badge>MainInfo/Label', formatter: 'sap.ui.model.odata.AnnotationHelper.format'}"/>
        <template:with path="badge>MainInfo" var="field">
            <core:Fragment fragmentName="sap.ui.core.sample.ViewTemplate.tiny.Field" type="XML"/>
        </template:with>

        <Label text="{path: 'badge>SecondaryInfo/Label', formatter: 'sap.ui.model.odata.AnnotationHelper.format'}"/>
        <template:with path="badge>SecondaryInfo" var="field">
            <core:Fragment fragmentName="sap.ui.core.sample.ViewTemplate.tiny.Field" type="XML"/>
        </template:with>
      </form:SimpleForm>
  </template:with>
</mvc:View>
```

This is cleaner and doesn't add the overhead of an additional control to wrap your fragment in.

---

**ORIGINAL POST**:

I ran across the same issue as yourself today. I wanted an XML fragment to have different binding contexts in the same View.

I found your [cross-post on SCN](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3775936) that had a reasonable solution by Maksim Rashchynski.

Since we can't apply a `binding` property to the `<core:Fragment />` definition, wrapping my fragment in a `sap.m.Panel` seemed to do the trick.

```xml
<Panel binding="{ path: 'myModel>/Some/ObjectA' }">
  <core:Fragment fragmentName="my.fragment.Something" type="XML" />
</Panel>

<Panel binding="{ path: 'myModel>/Some/ObjectB' }">
  <core:Fragment fragmentName="my.fragment.Something" type="XML" />
</Panel>
```

While inside my fragment, I had:

```xml
<Label text="asdf" />
<Text text="{myModel>Comments}" />
```

Make sure you do not use absolute binding inside your fragment.

> For those unaware, relative binding does not use a `/` in the binding path. Relative binding: `{Comments}`, Absolute binding: `{/Comments}`.

Answer (score 0):

You could give your HBox an identifier and bind it to the specific entity using [bindElement](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Element.html#bindElement) depending on wether it is a Creator or not. By doing this you can use the binding as in your first fragment.

Comment: is there a way doing it in xml? Since I'm using xml view, I hope I can build the UI declaratively, there must be a binding syntax in xml.

Comment: You're already using binding syntax in your view. What you want is that the view determines the binding context as well. I would suggest to do this in a controller as this makes your fragment really reusable.